# return value in a dictionary that's within a list, the whole thing in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have an empty table in SQL management studio that I’d like to populate with values for each sentence. The table has 3 columns – SentId, Word, Count.

My sentence has this structure:

```
sentence = {‘features’: [{}, {}, {}…] , ‘id’: 1234}
```

-->To fill out SentId values, I call SQL “insert into table values (provide 3 values for 3 columns here)” statement, entering sentence[‘id’], which returns 1234. That’s simple. With a next step I have problems.

-->To get values for Word and Count columns, I need to get inside ‘features’ which has this structure:

```
‘features’: [ {‘word’:’ hello’, ‘count’: 2}, {‘word’: ’there’, ‘count’:1}, {}, {}…]
```

I ran this so far:

```
sentence = {'features': [{'word': 'hello', 'count': 2}, {'word': 'there', 'count':1}] , 'id': 1234}
print(sentence['features'])
    #out>>  [{'word': 'hello', 'count': 2}, {'word': 'there', 'count': 1}]
```

So I need to get inside the dictionary that is within a list.
This didn`t work:

```
print(sentence['features'].get("word"))
```

Thanks so much for helping me out. I am new to programming.

Comment: sentence['features'][0]['word']

Comment: don`t flag me with -1; help me instead. thank you

Comment: THANKS!!!! I gonna delete my stupid question soon

Comment: ahhhh. I can`t delete it. Shame on me forever. xD Moderator please delete it, man. Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

As you can maybe see for yourself, sentence['features'] returns a list. Not a dictionary.
In order to get an element from a list in Python, you need to index it.

```
a=[1,2,3]
print(a[0]) #would print 1
```

So in your case, that would lead to the following code:

```
print(sentence['features'][0].get("word"))
```

sentence['features'][0] returns the first dictionary, in which you then return the value for the key 'word'.
If you want to loop over all the items in the list you can do:

```
for i in sentence['features']:
    print(i['word'])
```

For further info, see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html